# How can I use a JSDoc comment to eliminate an "Unresolved function or method" warning in WebStorm or other JetBrains products?

Tags: ide, webstorm, jetbrains-ide, jsdoc

In WebStorm, PyCharm, and other JetBrains products you can use JSDoc comments to inform WebStorm that an object does have a specific property, thereby eliminating a warning.

Either `@namespace` or `@property` works well for plain object properties, but I can't find a JSDoc command that works for functions.

```
const query = require(...);
...
Object.keys(record)
    .forEach(col => {
        query.set(col, record[col]);
    });
```

In the snippet above, `.set(...)` is not recognized by WebStorm and produces an *Unresolved function or method* warning.

This is only a single example. My project uses multiple third-party libraries and many of those libraries have object methods that trigger the warning on use. There are no typescript definitions available for these libraries, and WebStorm's file analysis doesn't pick up on them.

I cannot modify the query object, nor can I change how it is imported. Is there a JSDoc comment I can add to eliminate the warning? I've tried multiple variations of *@property*, *@param*, *@namespace*, and *@member*.

#### notes:

I know that the warning can be disabled by using a `// noinspection JSUnresolvedFunction` on the line directly above the use of the function, but this is an inferior solution. The JSDoc comments can be placed in multiple scopes, such as the start of the class or function definition. The JSDoc solution also improves readability and has meaning in other, non-JetBrains IDEs.

Comment: I guess that adding `/** @type {...} */` above import should work

Comment: This suggestion worked. For the above sample code I needed to add `/** @type {Object} query; @property {Function} query.set */` *directly* above `const query = require...`. If you want to write up your comment as an answer I will accept it, otherwise I will make it an answer myself.

Comment: thank you, i have added a bit more extended answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

JSDoc provides the way to explicitly annotate symbols with `@type`

So in your example it's could be:

```
/** @type {QueryObjectTypeDef} */
const query = require(...);
```

Also same effect could be achieved (tested in WebStorm) with inline annotation of function args:

```
forEach((/* ColTypeDef */ col) => {...})
```